# Getting Primary Key from database (Python / Django)

Tags: python, django, database, primary-key, hashids

I'm trying to use [Hashids](http://hashids.org/python/) which works when I manually input the number to encode, but doesn't work if I try to get it to encode the Primary Key from each table row.

models.py

```
from hashids import Hashids
from django.db import models

class AddToDatabase(models.Model):

    hashids = Hashids()
                                  # hasids.encode(123) works correctly
    slug = models.CharField(default=hashids.encode(pk), max_length=12)
```

The above says pk is undefined, regardless of what I try to import.

Comment: y need to override model save method to able to make slug field equal the pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying now(Since `pk` will get value only after `INSERT` operation). One option is

```
class AddToDatabase(models.Model):
    hashids = Hashids()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddToDatabase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = self.hashids.encode(self.pk)
        super(AddToDatabase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense, however it's giving me an error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'slug'`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is calculating `hashid` on demand

```
class AddToDatabase(models.Model):

    @property
    def slug(self):
        hashids = Hashids()
        return hashids.encode(self.pk)
```